# Activity Classification through LOG file

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, lstm, dynamic-time-warping

I have a big dataset containing logs/steps that the user performed on my webpage (for example: Clicking on a "Homepage" button, typing some text in the field, etc.) These steps are labelled against their respective action/class name (each set of steps belong to a specific class), what kind of ML algo can I apply on this kind of problem so that i can classify the steps to a respective activity/class?

Special NOTE: each of these "classes"/"activities" have multiple steps under them, and I don't know whether a simple classification algo such as LR or KNN would work....

example data: This is just one class data, and the data is arranged in this format:

```
{ CLass : [Title>>Header>>Action>>Input_Field , Title2>>Header2>>Action>>Input_Field]}
```

I tried a DTW and pattern matching algo for matching an input sequence to the given json data.